# Is there any way to simulate keyboard input?

Tags: android

I tried to use:

```
(new Instrumentation()).sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H);
```

but I want to use it on other applications so I would need the INJECT_EVENTS permission which is only for system-apps (or rooted devices).

So, is there any possibility to input text outside of my app without system-app permissions?

Comment: adb shell input text "Your text here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  On purpose-  they don't want you to be able to pretend to be the user to other apps for security reasons.  (Also-  the keyboard actually probably doesn't send key events-  only hardware keyboards do.  So even if it worked, you may not get the result you expect because an input connection isn't active and tied to an individual view).  If you do find a way, expect google to patch it with the next release.